# Javascript date.setFullYear changes day of month in FF and Safari

Tags: javascript

Here in this snippet we set year, but day of month is also changed (was 05 and became 04):

```
> d = new Date('2015-03-05')
Date 2015-03-05T00:00:00.000Z
> d.setFullYear('2014')
Date 2014-03-04T23:00:00.000Z
```

Setting date is also weird:

```
d.setDate(5)
Date 2014-03-04T20:00:00.000Z
```

But this not true for another year:

```
> d1 = new Date('2016-03-05')
Date 2016-03-05T00:00:00.000Z
> d1.setFullYear(2015)
Date 2015-03-05T00:00:00.000Z
```

This weird behaviour take plase in FF, so how it should be handled ?

Comment: Does it work with `setUTCFullYear`?

Comment: @dfr in which timezone are you? i guess it is +1 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Date.prototype.setFullYear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setFullYear) set the date based on your local time
And the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor when called with one date string argument sets time as UTC no local time

So, you should either:

- use [Date.prototype.setUTCFullYear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setUTCFullYear)
- add the timezone to your date string
- create the date object with multiple arguments